# Flutter: How to deobfuscate a stack trace?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, stack-trace

I am trying to deobfuscate a flutter stack trace using the command, where err.txt is my stack trace file -

```
flutter symbolize -i err.txt -d /out/android/app.android-arm64.symbols
```

However, on running I get an error, I require a file called app.android-arm64.symbols to deobfuscate my stack trace but I don't know where to find this file, as this isn't mentioned clearly in the Flutter documentation. This is the error I get:

```
 /out/android/app.android-arm64.symbols does not exist
```

Can someone help me out on how to do this?

Comment: You can't 'deobfuscate' using something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @user207421 I've updated my question to be more precise as to what I need help with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbols are generated while building the apk/bundle so you could check there.

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Firstly for obfuscation you need to run this command - > 
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate

With this command the symbol files will be generated in the path which you have mentioned in the obfuscated command,
Then Create a txt file in your project and copy the obfuscated stacktrace in that file..

then follow this -> https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2644 , Which says Remove (.java) and add 4 spaces
Then Run this command - > 
flutter symbolize -i <stack trace file> -d /out/android/app.android-arm64.symbols
```